# One liner to re-size two matrices to the same size as the smaller matrix

Tags: matlab, resize

Say i have two matrices: `A` and `B` and they are two different sizes. For eg:

```
A = [1 2]

B = [3 4 5]
```

What i want to do is crop the matrix that is bigger and remove any elements. ie. in the above case you would have:

```
A = [1 2] <- Stays the same because it's smaller

B = [3 4] <- Cropped to same size as A.
```

Now i could do it so easily with a bunch of boring `if` and `else` statements but i was hoping a wizard or witch would help me uncover the magic matlab syntax that will do this in one line.

Assume that they are always 3xN ie. vectors.

Comment: Hehe, this is tricky. :-) Normally the usual assignment expressions are incapable of assigning two matrices in the same time (unless the result comes from a previously defined function---but defining auxiliary functions does not fall in one-liner category). But is a cool puzzle, nevertheless...

Comment: @CST-Link: you could do a one-liner using [disperse](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33866-disperse), in case that should really be necessary.

Comment: @Jonas Then the result would come from a previously defined function, wouldn't it? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the size only differs along the second dimension, you can crop the arrays like this:

```
colA = size(A,2);
colB = size(B,2);

A = A(:,1:min(colA,colB))
B = B(:,1:min(colA,colB))
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work on multi-dim matrix too, basically the same as Jonas answer.

```
d = min([size(A); size(B)]);
A = A(1:d(1),1:d(2));
B = B(1:d(1),1:d(2));
```

I wonder how a size matrix (like [2 4]) can be transformed into index ie [1:2, 1:4])...